# En un Login, ¿Cómo invoco a una acción de un controlador?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Buen día
Estoy implementando un Login en mi aplicación y deseo que una vez que las credenciales son las correctas invocar a una acción que devuelve una vista, este es el código que implemente.

```
@model IEnumerable<Inventario.Domain.Entities.Usuario>

@{
Layout = null;
ViewBag.Title = "Ingreso a la aplicación";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Login</title>

@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/jqgrid")    

</head>
<body>        

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">                
            <br />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
            <h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
            <label for="Usuario">Usuario:</label>
            <input type="text" id="UsuarioID" name="UsuarioID" class="form-control" />
            <label for="Password">Password:</label>
            <input type="text" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" />
            <br />
            <input type="button" id="btnAceptar" value="Aceptar" class="btn btn-info" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="error-message">
    </div>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqgrid")


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#UsuarioID").focus();

        $("#btnAceptar").click(function () {
            IngresoAplicacion();
        });
    });

    function IngresoAplicacion() {

        var usuario = $("#UsuarioID").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();

        var usuario = {
            "usuario": {
                "UsuarioID": $("#UsuarioID").val(),
                "Password": $("#password").val()
            }
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Login")',
            data: JSON.stringify(usuario),
            contentType: "application/json;charser=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            complete: function (resultado) {
                debugger;
                var resultadoAjax = JSON.parse(resultado.responseText);
                if (resultadoAjax.Exito) {
                    //Aquí es donde necesito Invocar a la acción para que devuelva una vista                        
                }
                else {
                    bootbox.alert(resultadoAjax.Mensaje);
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                debugger;
                bootbox.alert(jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        });

    };

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Estuve intentando con
    window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Bienvenido")';
Pero no me funciono, entonces intente con
    window.location.assign = '@Url.Action("Bienvenido")';
llegó a ingresar pero la vista bienvenido solapa a la vista login y se ve muy mal.

**Quisiera saber cómo se tiene invocar desde el Jquery a una acción de un controlador.**

Este es el código de mi controlador

```
using Inventario.Data.Model;
using Inventario.Data.Repositories;
using Inventario.Domain.Entities;
using Inventario.Web.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Inventario.Web.Controllers
{
public class UsuarioController : Controller
{
    private UsuarioRepository repoUsuario = null;

    public UsuarioController()
    {
        repoUsuario = new UsuarioRepository(new InventarioContext());
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Login()
    {            
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(Usuario usuario)
    {
        try
        {
            //Obtiene datos del usuario
            var usuarioValidar = repoUsuario.ObtieneCredenciales(usuario);

            //credenciales correctas
            if (usuarioValidar.Count() > 0)
            {
                //Session["UserId"] = usuarioValidar.AsQueryable().Select(u => u.UsuarioID);
                Session["UserId"] = usuario.UsuarioID.ToString();
                return RedirectToAction("Bienvenido");
            }
            else
            {
                Session["UserId"] = null;                    
            }

            return Json(new ResultadoAjax() { Exito = true, Mensaje = "Ingreso satisfactorio a la aplicación." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return Json(new ResultadoAjax() { Exito = false, Mensaje = "Problemas para ingresar a la aplicación." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }


    }

    public ActionResult Bienvenido()
    {
        if (Session["UserId"] != null)
        {
            return View();                
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Porque usas ajax para hacer la petición y luego cambias la url tu mismo con javascript? No sería mejor hacer un POST con un formulario común y corriente y que el server cambiara la url por tí al regreso sin usar ajax. El resultado es el mismo y no hay que escribir tanto código.

Comment: @devconcept, si uso AJAX es por el tema del renderizado parcial, lo que mencionas es `válido` y se puede hacer, lo que yo queria saber es que si lo puedo invocar desde el Jquery, por eso relice dicha `implementación`

Comment: Si se puede lograr. `@Url.Action("Accion")` generará una url y `window.location.assign` hará que el navegador cambie hacia esa url. La razón de mi comentario es que estas haciendo manualmente lo que el navegador puede hacer por ti. Si estas intentando que todas tus páginas carguen via AJAX deberías usar un framework SPA como angular, ember o react con react-router que ya traen incluido ruteo por ajax y tu servidor sólo tiene que mandarle `json` y `html` al cliente. Sino, deberías dejar que el controller cumpla su funcion con `return View` y `return RedirectToAction` para controlar el flujo.

Comment: @devconcept, agradezco tu respuesta, lo tendré en consideración. Aprovechando aquello, tendras alguna referencia de como realizar esos trabajos con el framework ember o react (no he tenido la oportunidad de trabajar con ellos).

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esto, fíjate en las dobles comillas (**" "**)

```
window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Bienvenido")";
```